# Создание векторного изображения из массива NumPy

Tags: python, svg, numpy

Я генерирую изображения, они сохраняются в растре. Но для печати они мне нужны в векторном формате. Можно ли как-то сразу сохранить изображения в SVG. Или же например PNG перегнать в массив, где каждое значение это номер цвета в RGB, а потом этот массив превратить в векторное изображение?

Comment: Сразу генерируйте изображения в векторе, потом если нужно - перегоняйте в растр. Обратная операция (сконвертировать растр в вектор) - это немного похоже на проворачивание фарша через мясорубку в обратную сторону. Технически это возможно (векторизация растровых изображений, не обратное проворачивание фарша), но проще сразу сразу генерировать вектор.

Comment: Ну, хотя, смотря что у вас за изображения. Если у вас просто массив пикселей сохраняется в png, то вообще нет смысла его перегонять в вектор.

Comment: Я генерирую data matrix теэги с помощью pystrich.datamatrix. И эта библиотека по умолчанию сохраняет только в растровых форматах

Comment: Может быть есть возможность генерации data matrix в вектор сразу?

Comment: Я посмотрел pystrich, там из векторных форматов поддерживается только dxf (условно, это формат для чертежей). Для svg что-то свое придется писать, но это по идее не очень сложно, нужно просто в [rendered.py](https://github.com/mmulqueen/pyStrich/blob/master/pystrich/datamatrix/renderer.py) сделать свой метод-рендерер, который по данным из self.matrix насоздает прямоугольников в нужных местах.

Comment: В принципе dxf поддерживается практически любым векторным редактором/просмотрщиком, так что для печати возможно вам и этот формат подойдет.

Comment: Благодарю за ценный совет. Надо попробовать!

Comment: Попытался я сконвертировать data matrix сразу в DXF, не получилось. Пишет что не поддерживает этот формат, странно... Возможно я где-то ошибся в написании кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pystrich.datamatrix import DataMatrixEncoder

encoder = DataMatrixEncoder("12345")
encoder.save("test.png")
print(encoder.get_ascii())
with open("test.dxf", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(encoder.get_dxf(inverse=True, cellsize=1))
```

необходимо вручную обновить библиотеку PyStich